# Get creation date and time of records in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, sync

We have dynamic CRM system which syncs data to marketing cloud however i need to find when the records were created in data extension ,
Sad part is i dont have default date field in it.
Help Please! , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of integration are you using? If you are receiving the records either via API of FTP, you can add a date field to the data extension, and set its default value to current time. This way, you will get the creation time of each of them:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply , data is already loaded into the Data extension via api and i'll take care to add the date field from next time